# How to Opt into Android TV in google play publishers console

Tags: android

I have developed my app to run on Android TV.In the previous google play publisher console I know there was opt in check boxes for TV and then add tv screen shots.But how can I opt in to TV in this new version of publisher play console.After I made the app for TV and upload the bundle ,in device catalog it show some TV's supported,some unsupported,some says not opt in. I dont understand how to opt in for these TV's.
IN new play console I cannot see opt in way.
The documentation in here https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist
is this still valid ?
or is there something silly that I don't understand.

Please can someone throw a light on this.
Many Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/publishing/checklist and https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tv-app-quality

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that the opt-in is now under release types in advanced settings

1. Release
2. Setup
3. Advanced Settings
4. Release Types
5. Add a new one for Android TV

Comment: Man ... it's annoying they did not update their docs.

Comment: Screenshot here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595856/android-tv-app-cant-be-installed-on-android-tv-devices/66641865#66641865

Answer (score 2):

may be its late but in current play console

1. click on `Setup` from left menu
2. click on `Advanced settings`
3. click on `Form factors` tab
4. click on `Add form factor`
5. select TV from menu and complete the requirement

your current release will be reviewed for TV app store.